# Doctrine tags to post relationship with value in between

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a flexible database structure, where i can assign any tag to any post and have a custom label-value for it

[image]

I have a perfectly working SQL query for it, but now i want to migrate it to Doctrine ORM and classic solution (as far as i've found) for that kind of design is:

```
class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private string $name;


    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: "post", targetEntity: PostTag::class)]
    private Collection $tags;
}


class PostTag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Post::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Post $post;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Tag::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Tag $tag;
}

class Tag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: "tag", targetEntity: PostTag::class)]
    private Collection $posts;
}
```

But problem is, later if you want to fetch post with all its attributes your code will look something like that:

```
    $repository = $em->getRepository(Post::class);
    $post = $repository->find(1); // fetch first Post from database

    $postTag = $post->getPostTags()->first(); // get first tag from all post tags
    $name = $postTag->getTag()->getName(); // post tag -> get tag, tautology at its best
    $value = $postTag->getValue(); // but value is in post tags list
```

And this solution works, but it's pretty ugly if you want to have tags `key => value` list, since in `Post` you first need to retrieve all `PostTags` and from each of them you retrieve `Tag` name one by one.

Image how much better would it look like this:

```
    $repository = $em->getRepository(Post::class);
    $post = $repository->find(1);

    $tag = $post->getTags()->first();
    $name = $tag->getName();
    $value = $tag->getValue();
```

But the only way i've achieved that is with `many-to-many` connection between `Post` and `Tag`, but then i don't have a `value` (of course, because `Tag` don't have that column), is there a solution to have a more clean entities code ?

Comment: have a look at `symfony/demo` project [BlogController.php](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/main/src/Controller/BlogController.php)

Comment: @AlexanderBr. You are suggesting skipping all joins and fetching straight from repositories the needed data?